# How to force execution of a code in a base class and let the user also write his implementation of the code?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I would like to create an abstract base class with a Run() method. Each time any child of this class need to run I will call this run() method. The implementation of the run must be in the child, not in the base class but I would like to be sure that I record the last run time and date after the run.

Here is my base class:

```
public abstract class Monitor
{
    public void Run()
    { 
        LastRun = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime LastRun { get; private set; }
}
```

Normally my method Run() must be abstract to force any user that implement Monitor to write the run body. But if abstract I cannot have a body in my base class. Is there  pattern for this?

Comment: You can add another `protected abstract void InternalRun()` method.

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```
public abstract class Monitor
{
    public void Run()
    { 
        RunImpl();
        LastRun = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected abstract void RunImpl();

    public DateTime LastRun { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider (not in all cases) wrapping the execution of `RunImpl` in a `try` block and the setting of the `LastRun` property in a `finally` block, just to make sure its set even if the `RunImpl` has thrown an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could also refactor to favor [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):

```cs
public class Monitor
{
    private Action run;
    public DateTime? LastRun { get; private set; }

    public Monitor(Action run) => this.run = run;

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(LastRun))]
    public void Run()
    { 
        run();
        LastRun = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

// client code:
static void MyRun() {}
var m = new Monitor(MyRun);
m.Run();
Console.WriteLine(m.LastRun.Value);
```

Comment: Quickly... What is the ```!``` after LastRun? I know the ```?``` but not the ```!```.

Comment: @BastienVandamme Leaving the `!` out will produce a compiler warning, because `LastRun` is nullable, but the code doesn't check that before accessing `Value`. Since we know the property won't be `null` after `Run()` we override that warning for this specific scenario.

Comment: @BastienVandamme I updated the code with a [`MemberNotNull` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#helper-methods-membernotnull-and-membernotnullwhen) which makes the `!` obsolete for all code *after* `m.Run()`.